What op_codes are used to inscribe "microstrategy orange" spam?
Other than pricing out peer-to-peer financial transactions out of the scarce blockspace, can such inscriptions also bloat the UTXO set of Bitcoin?
What op_codes are used to inscribe the decentralized identity content.

According to the specification, data for IDs is embedded into the blockchain through either OP_RETURN outputs, or through inscriptions.
OP_RETURN outputs have no effect on the UTXO set since they are provably unspendable and are therefore never inserted into it.
Inscriptions look like any other Taproot output, so will initially have an effect on the UTXO set in the output's creation. Storing the data on the blockchain requires spending the UTXO in order to reveal the data that is present in the tapscript. This necessarily removes the UTXO from the UTXO set, and is therefore a net neutral interaction on the UTXO set. Since their protocol requires the information to be revealed, it is unlikely that the data stored in this method will have any measurable effect on the UTXO set.
The inscriptions method uses the same script opcodes and construction that ordinals' inscriptions do.
